# what is the origin of the term travel

Tags: meaning, etymology

What is the origin of the term travel and how broad is the term travel? What is it intended to encompass?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you demonstrate your efforts at research prior to asking, perhaps by [checking the Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=travel) or other dictionaries. If these are inadequate, then please explain why. I encourage you to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

It is derived from 'travail' and obviously in olden times, travelling by sea being the 'real travel' involved lot of travails.  The journey and experience, if not hardship, is what the word 'travel' encompasses.

Answer (score 1):

The english word ***travel*** is related to [travail:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=travel&allowed_in_frame=0)

> late 14c., "to journey,"
>
> from travailen (1300) "to make a journey," originally "to toil, labor"
> (see [travail](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=travail&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> ["labor, toil," mid-13c.,
>
> from Old French travail "work, labor, toil, suffering or painful
> effort, trouble; arduous journey" (12c.),
>
> from travailler "to toil, labor," originally "to trouble, torture,
> torment,"
>
> from Vulgar Latin *tripaliare "to torture,"
>
> from *tripalium (in Late Latin trepalium) "instrument of torture,"
>
> probably from Latin tripalis "having three stakes" (from tria "three;"
> see three + palus "stake;"
>
> see pale (n.)), which sounds ominous, but the exact notion is obscure.
> The verb is recorded from late 13c. in English, from the verb in Old
> French.]
>
> The semantic development may have been via the notion of "go on a
> difficult journey," but it also may reflect the difficulty of any
> journey in the Middle Ages.
>
> [[Etymonline.com]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=travel&allowed_in_frame=0)